# Oracle plsql how to select if two counts are equal

Tags: sql, oracle

I wish to select data from a table if, and only if, the unique mobile numbers are equal to the total number of rows in a table (i.e. we dont have two different people with the same mobile number, and/or we don't have a row with null values in the mobile number column), where there is a specific area code, e.g. 4817.

At the moment, I have the query bellow (which does not work with the AND constraint). Does anyone have any tips on how to do this?

```
SELECT  
  MOB_NUM   AS MOBILE_NUMBER,
  NAME      AS NAME,
  AREA_CODE AS AREA_CODE

  FROM DB_PHONEBOOK DBP
  WHERE DBP.AREA_CODE = 4817
  AND (COUNT(DISTINCT DBP.MOB_NUM ) = COUNT(DBP.MOB_NUM))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Individual rows/records are filtered using `Where` clause where as groups like count/Sum/Average/.. are filtered using `Having` clause

If am not wrong you are looking for something like this

```
SELECT DBP.MOB_NUM   AS MOBILE_NUMBER,
       DBP.NAME      AS NAME,
       DBP.AREA_CODE AS AREA_CODE
FROM   DB_PHONEBOOK DBP
       INNER JOIN (SELECT MOB_NUM
                   FROM   DB_PHONEBOOK DBP
                   WHERE  DBP.AREA_CODE = 4817
                   GROUP  BY MOB_NUM
                   HAVING Count(DISTINCT DBP.MOB_NUM) = Count(DBP.MOB_NUM)) C_DBP
               ON DBP.MOB_NUM = C_DBP.MOB_NUM
WHERE  DBP.AREA_CODE = 4817
```

Comment: Not sure why you would use the `INNER JOIN`, but pointing out the `HAVING` really helped! Thanks!

Comment: @Captainslow - Without that `INNER JOIN` you can't select `NAME` and `AREA_CODE`. If you don't want those two in result then you just use the inner select query